# What is a Multi-Hop Cycle Detected response?

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy

Setting up a reverse proxy using IIS 7.5, here is the request/response path:

Client (network 1) <--> IIS 7.5 Proxy (network 1) <--> Weblogic Server (network 2)

The client receives an http 400 response (Multi-Hop Cycle Detected) from the reverse proxy server. What does that mean?

Comment: Most likely, it probably means you are trying to use the proxy to reach the proxy.

Comment: What type of authentication is being used? Kerberos? NTLM? Forms? Basic?